# How to export AviSynth project to video file?

Tags: export

I am just starting on AviSynth for video production. My understanding is that AviSynth only does frameserving and not file export, but several [export filters](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/TWriteAVI#Export_Filters) are available. `TWriteAVI` seems the tool for the job but the [plugin link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/84csi0174ettu5l/TWriteAVI_dll_v2.03-20160603.zip) is no longer available on the host.

The title links [to a forum](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=172837) with what looks like VB code:

```
#######

ForceProcessAVI(clip c,bool "Debug"=True)
 Force Process clip c, ie read from first to last frame, for TWriteAVI writes the AVI file (Video + Audio) without having to play clip.
...
```

I didn't see how to turn this code into an executable, as I mostly use Unix and Windows is for AviSynth only.

How can I hook this code into AviSynth, or how can I export an `.avs` text file to a movie file?

Answer (score 2):

Forget about output filters.

Use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/)  (Linux, Mac, [Windows](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)) with this simple command

```
ffmpeg -i your_avs_file.avs  output.mp4
```

(or `output.avi`, `output.mkv`, ...),

or any conversion program which accepts `.avs` files as input, e. g. [Any Video Converter Free](https://www.any-video-converter.com/products-freeware/) (for Mac and Windows).

---

*Note 1:*

The Windows link points to the site for downloading Zeranoe's FFmpeg build. Unpack the downloaded file and use it — no installation is needed, perhaps only adding the path to `ffmpeg.exe` into your `PATH` environment variable.

*Note 2:*

If you want build FFmpeg by yourself, don't forget add `--enable-avisynth` option.

*Note 3:*

You may directly play back your AviSynth script files (.avs) with some Media Players, e.g. with Media Player Classic.

Comment: I followed these steps and after the usual `ffmpeg` boilerplate, I get `Unknown error occurred` and no other information.